# Find $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that$A^2=B^2=I$, and pairs $\{\frac{1}{2}, 2\}$ and $3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$ be eigenvalues of $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find matrices $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2=B^2=I$ and pairs $\{\frac{1}{2}, 2\}$ and $3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$ be eigenvalues of matrix $AB$.

Comment: How can the $2 \times 2$ matrix $AB$ have four distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, considers pairs $\{\frac{1}{2}, 1\}$ and $3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$. actually $AB$ can one form of eigenvalues.

Comment: I know that spectrum of $AB$ is as form $\{z,\frac{1}{z}\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Taking $A = I$ and $B = -I$ we also would need to include $-1$. For any occuring eigenvalue the inverse must also occur, so we also would need $2$.

Comment: post has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1 & 1\\
0 & -1
}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{
1 & 0\\
1/2 & -1
}
$$
and
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1 & 1\\
0 & -1
}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{
1 & 0\\
4 & -1
}
$$

**My process:** it helps to consider $\operatorname{trace}(AB)$.